# How to set Microsoft Word document section or paragraph to read only using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there a way to set an ms word document section/paragraph to read only programmatically? I am aware of restricting to read only in word as described by the below link.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restrict-or-permit-formatting-changes-69ca7857-db43-4785-9e14-7735db6d79bb

However I need to do it in C# because I need to check first if the user is in SharePoint group.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

[First extend your document:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668196(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

[Then Protect it:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230379.aspx)

```
extendedDocument.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, true, "password", true);
```

Edit: [see more about working with an IRM to more securely protect your documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-restricting-access-with-Information-Rights-Management-af6c2f52-6a00-4a7a-917f-8b2ab094389d#bmwd)

Edit: [see more about how to use the protect method:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230379.aspx)